# Retrieving textBox handles

Tags: c#, winforms-interop

I'm currently working on a project to provide interop between two unrelated pieces of software. I need to pass the data from a textBox/textBoxes, into a textBox of the other said app.

My current idea is to find the handle of the target control, make it active, and enter the data by copying it to the clipboard, and pasting it via:

```
Clipboard.SetText(textBox1.Text, TextDataFormat.Text);
SendKeys.SendWait("^V");
```

As textBoxes have no 'caption', handles are dynamically assigned on the process start, and class names are appended with various data regarding the process, is it possible to get a handle for an object within a window via some sort of indexing? I'd be more than willing to find the correct handle by trial and error if need be, as long as it would be consistent for every instance of the application.

Thanks in advance

A.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any other choice.. to make this easier, you can use AutoIT.. I had to do something like this a very long time ago.  [AutoIT](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/).  They have a DLL for .net Applications, so you can use their functionality without having to use their scripts.  If you do use their scripts.. they also have an option that will turn their script into an executable.

Comment: Ideally, I would like to keep this as clean c# scripting. This is for our own software, that supports .NET scripting via our own API for customer system integration. The main issue here is targeting the 3rd party software properly without any available interface.

Comment: You can use AutoIT.. as an API to effectively allow that.  It gets rid of all the Win32 window handling code.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misread.
I might have go and see how this works out. 
Thanks